# PHPWord generated docx watermark image with 0 margin is shifted with some space from left and top edge of document

Tags: watermark, phpword

I generate a docx document with PHPWord and want to make an image to be as a background. Watermark is totally the point for it.
Everything works fine generating document like sections, paragraphs, font styles and sizes, line heights, etc. 
But I stucked with this part: my image for background with margins 0 is always shifted with some space from the document's edge.

I go with this code:

```
$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
$section = $phpWord->addSection();

$header = $section->addHeader();
$header->addWatermark($path . '/images/test.jpg', 
  array(
    'marginTop' => 0, 
    'marginLeft'=> 0,
  )
);

$section->addText('Is Richard Deckard a replicant?');

$timestamp = date('Hi-ymd');
$filename = 'DOC_' . $timestamp;
$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save($path . '/docs/' . $filename . '.docx');
```

The result is:
[PHPWord watermark image for background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4f8i.png)

So as you see margins are not 0 but the image is some distance from the left and top edge of the page.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? Your issue seems to be related to the automatic section margins. I was able to remove them by setting it to 0, but then you run into printing problems with no margin.

Answer (score 2):

I was able positioning background image to the top-left edge this way

```
$header = $section->addHeader();
$header->addWatermark('images/test.png', 
  array(
    'width' => 596, 
    'marginTop' => -36,
    'marginLeft' => -50,
    'posHorizontal' => 'absolute',
    'posVertical' => 'absolute',
  ));
```

I think the point is the absolute parameter.
I needed to make negative values on margins, because my body section had inner margins.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and fortunately I found this question and the answer from @vorvor. Thank you for the answer @vorvor.

I did the same thing in a Laravel 5.6 project and just wanted to share my code with you.

```
$header = $section->addHeader();
$bg_image = Storage::url('itinerary-assets/Untitled-1_compressed.jpg');
$header->addWatermark($bg_image, [
    'marginTop' => -36,
    'marginLeft' => -50,
    'posHorizontal' => 'absolute',
    'posVertical' => 'absolute'
]);
```